# Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) in xaml

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

my Project copy was fine. but after few edits in some other class files above errors poped out [irrespective of me doing some thing]. I am totally blind in what to do

Following is the comment in my xaml that is causing the problem.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayBackground}"/>
```

Comment: What's the resource GrayBackground? Did you change it from Brush to a Color? Or/also, what is this setter attached to?

Comment: You are missing resources !